# Connection Issues via Testing Capsule

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am currently developing a capsule for Bixby and was trying to test the capsule on some S8 and S9 devices.
Every time I give in a vocal/keyboard input for the capsule to operate on, the result is always the same message:

**"Oh, there was a connection problem. Please try again"**

What is more is that when I try out other capsule phrases provided by Bixby (ex. "Find the nearest restaurants with Google Maps"), the result is the same with the connection error message.

The Bixby Studio that I am currently developing with is **Version 6.15.0, 19M Capsule SDK**.
The Bixby (Voice) version being used is **Version 2.1.24.0**.
Developer mode was on.

Furthermore, the phone devices that were being tested on are Samsung S8 and S9.

Based on the Bixby Studio Simulator, the capsule is working fine, as the phrase "plumbers near me" actually provides a list of plumbers/plumbing services.

Comment: Are you certain that the devices are connected to the internet either by cellular or wifi?

Comment: I would suggest opening a ticket with bixby developer support and include additional details like the time (&timezone), date and capsule name.

Comment: @JPAlioto All devices have been connected. If I turn developer mode off, all the other capsules in the marketplace, such as Google Maps and Yelp, will work.